# Visual Studio Fails to Recognize Controls

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012

using VS2011 beta;

In the web.config I have a `<add  tagPrefix="aa1" assembly="MyProject" namespace="MyProject" />`

Why, in my aspx file, when I write `<aa1:MyControl runat="server" />`, do I get `Unrecognized tag prefix or device filter 'aa1'`

And when I put a `<%@ Register TagPrefix="aa1" Namespace="MyProject" Assembly="MyProject" %>` in the aspx

I get `Element 'MyControl' is not a known element. This can occur if there is a compilation error in the Web site, or the web.config file is missing.`

Both warnings don't block the build, and it actually seems to work fine, on deployment. But I can't figure out why VS is not playing along.

Comment: Because it's a beta version, possibly still containing several bugs like this? :) Have you tried it in VS 10?

Comment: if all your controls are not recognised then please check below option
if you change your page name then this type of error can occur just change class name to that of aspx page name here is example

public partial class User_Register : System.Web.UI.Page

<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/User/UserPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Register.aspx.cs" Inherits="User_Register" %>

Comment: @walther Makes sense. I currently have only 11 running...